# Help with Grid Lines in a pgfplot (Version 2)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

This is a follow-up question to [Help with grid lines in a pgfplot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247541/help-with-grid-lines-in-a-pgfplot?rq=1)

I edited the code in that post to get a grid on the Cartesian plane that is closer to what I want.

Here is what I have. By specifying `grid=both,` and `grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},` and`xmin=-10.5`, `xmax=10.5`, `ymin=-10.5`,and `ymax=10.5` in the `axis` environment, I think that `TikZ` draws 20 horizontal gray lines and 20 vertical gray lines.  I think `major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},` in the `axis` environment should instruct `TikZ` to draw some darker help lines. It doesn't.  I tried specifying `xtick={-10, -5, 5, 10},`, `ytick={-10, -5, 5, 10},`, `ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},`, and `extra x ticks={-9, -8, -7, -6, -4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9},` to get `TikZ` to draw the "major grid" through `x=-10`, `x=-5`, `x=5`, and `x=10`.  That didn't work.

Here are some features that need to be included.  Tick marks at `-10`, `-5`, `5`, and `10` are to be typeset on both axes and "over the grid lines."   Implementing this code, they are all under the grid ... but there 
is a horizontal white strip  below the  x-axis and to the left of the y-axis, except for the typesetting of `-10`, `-5`, `5`, and `10`. Why is this horizontal white strip there?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title=An Illustration of Lattice Paths, title style={align=center,font=\bfseries},
    grid=both,grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
    xmin=-10,xmax=10,ymin=-10,ymax=10,
    axis lines=middle,
    xtick={-10, -5, 5, 10},
    ytick={-10, -5, 5, 10},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    extra x ticks={-9, -8, -7, -6, -4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9},
    extra x tick labels={},
    extra y ticks={-9, -8, -7, -6, -4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9},
    extra y tick labels={},
    minor tick num=4,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    axis line style={shorten >=-7.5pt, shorten <=-7.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
    ]

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\node[fill=white,circle,inner sep=0.5pt] (O-label) at ($(O)+(-135:10pt)$) {$\scriptstyle{O}$};
\coordinate (A) at (-3,9);
\node[fill=white,circle,inner sep=0.5pt] (A-label) at ($(A)+(-180:10pt)$) {$\scriptstyle{A}$};
\coordinate (B) at (7,-3);
\node[fill=white,circle,inner sep=0.5pt] (B-label) at ($(B)+(-45:10pt)$) {$\scriptstyle{B}$};

\draw[fill] (O) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (A) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (B) circle (1.5pt);

%These commands are for drawing a path from O to A.
\coordinate (A1) at (-1,0);
\coordinate (A2) at (-1,3);
\coordinate (A3) at (-3,3);

\draw[line width=1pt] (O) -- (A1) -- (A2) -- (A3) -- (A);

%These commands are for drawing a path from O to B.
\coordinate (B1) at (2,0);
\coordinate (B2) at (2,-2);
\coordinate (B3) at (5,-2);
\coordinate (B4) at (5,-3);
\coordinate (B) at (7,-3);

\draw[line width=1pt] (O) -- (B1) -- (B2) -- (B3) -- (B4) -- (B);

\coordinate (P) at (4,6);
\node[fill=white,circle,inner sep=0.5pt] (P-label) at ($(P)+(45:10pt)$) {$\scriptstyle{P}$};
\draw[fill] (P) circle (1.5pt);

\coordinate (Q) at (-7,-7);
\node[fill=white,circle,inner sep=0.5pt] (Q-label) at ($(Q)+(-135:10pt)$) {$\scriptstyle{Q}$};
\draw[fill] (Q) circle (1.5pt);

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Why did you remove the link to the previous question?

Comment: @Alenanno  Sorry.  `Undo` that.

Comment: @Alenanno  Hit the wrong icon.  What is "rollback"?

Comment: Rollback reverts the changes to the revision where you clicked `rollback`. :)

Comment: @Alenanno  In this case, I had just put a post on this web site.  You modified it.  I hit `rollback`, and this web site returned the post to the way I had it.  Is that right?

Comment: Yes. If you click on "edited ... mins ago" you'll see the revisions history. :)

Answer (score 1):

> I think `major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50}`, in the axis environment should instruct TikZ to draw some darker help lines. It doesn't.

It does. Try reducing it to `.1pt`, and you'll still distinguish them from the other lines which are `line width=.1pt,gray!10`. See image below for a demonstration of this.

> I tried specifying xtick={-10, -5, 5, 10},, ytick={-10, -5, 5, 10},, ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},, and extra x ticks={-9, -8, -7, -6, -4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9}, to get TikZ to draw the "major grid" through x=-10, x=-5, x=5, and x=10. That didn't work.

I don't understand why you're trying to do new things, when the code I gave you in the previous question draws the lines exactly through those points. Probably you didn't understand the code (it can happen), but the code already does that. See:

[image]

The command `minor tick num=#` is the number of ticks (not tick labels) between each major tick.

So in this case you have 0, 5, 10. If you write `minor tick num=4`, you'll get four ticks.

So from 0 to 5: 1,2,3,4.
And from 5 to 10: 6,7,8,9.

Four numbers = four ticks. See again image above to see this in action.

Hope this helps.

**Edit**: In response to your comment:

> Suppose that I want a grid on the Cartesian plane with xmin=-52, and xmax=52, and ymin=-11,ymax=17, and that I want the major grid style to be implemented at vertical lines that are multiples of 13 from the y-axis and at horizontal lines that are multiples of 5 from the y-axis.

I can't do that plane here because it's too big, but I'll provide a small example to explain the same concept. If you leave the ticks alone, the default is multiples of 5: `{0,5,10,...}`, but you can change this for each axis independently. When you set the ticks for a certain axis, *those* will be considered major ticks for that axis. So if you say `{-9,-6,-3,0,3,6,9}`, then these will be the major ticks.

Of course, if the ticks are too many but you know the steps, you can simply write `xtick={-9,-6,...,9},` and the result is the same. You define starting and ending point, and then the second number is used to define the step. Since between 9 and 6, you have 3 numbers, then the step is 3.

If the two axes are different, we will need to specify the minor ticks for each axis independently using

```
minor x tick num={4},
minor y tick num={4},
```

And this is the result:

[image: figure 1]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
    xmin=-11.75,xmax=11.75,
    ymin=-11.75,ymax=11.75,
    xtick={-9,-6,...,9},
    ytick={},
    grid=both,
    minor x tick num={4},
    minor y tick num={4},
    enlargelimits={abs=0},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\node[fill=white,circle,inner sep=0pt] (O-label) at ($(O)+(-135:10pt)$) {$\scriptstyle{O}$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I understand the code, but I'm not sure how `TikZ` can adapt it to an asymmetric display.  Suppose that I want a grid on the Cartesian plane with `xmin=-52,` and `xmax=52,` and `ymin=-11,ymax=17,` and that I want the `major grid style` to be implemented at vertical lines that are multiples of 13 from the y-axis and at horizontal lines that are multiples of 5 from the y-axis.  (At your suggestion from the other post, I want to include `axis line style={shorten >=-7.5pt, shorten <=-7.5pt},`.)

Comment: @user74973 See edit.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation.  Very nice!  Please affirm the following paraphrases.  If you omit the specification of ticks on the axes or include `xtick={\empty},ytick={},`, for example, the default for the `major grid style`  is multiples of 5:  `{... -10, -5, 0,5,10,...}`.  If you have `xmin=-52,` and `xmax=52` and `xtick={-52, -39,..., 52},` and `ymin=-11,` and `ymax=17,` and `ytick={-9,-6,...,15},` the `major grid style` will be vertical lines that are integral multiples of 13 from the y-axis and horizontal lines that are integral multiples of 3 from the x-axis.

Comment: In case you are not weary of talking about grid lines, I posted another question.  The title is "Help with Grid Lines in a pgfplot (Version 3)"