# Plotting of a triple data file in a colorful figure using pgfplots or tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a data file including three columns of data. I want to make a plot as

1. The first column is the x-axes.
2. The second column is the y-axes.
3. The third column is a colorful circle or square depending on the magnitude of data.

I want to plot this figure in latex using pgfplot or tikz. How can I do that?

The data file contains:

```
45. 25. 0.61566929
49. 27. 1.4956423
53. 29. 1.0057851
54. 29. 2.0100065
55. 29. -3.797218
68. 35. 1.5912051
69. 35. 3.2076212
72. 37. 1.4886461
73. 37. 3.3389691
76. 39. 3.0976278
77. 39. 0.79048738
81. 41. -3.4879389
85. 43. 3.6111543
93. 47. 2.7246307
97. 49. -0.68090255
104.    51. -2.0629526
105.    51. -2.6273176
108.    53. -0.89579787
109.    53. 1.2111116
112.    55. 0.91267194
113.    55. 2.0789467
117.    57. -0.71531635
121.    59. -2.3426783
127.    61. -1.8874818
128.    61. 1.3249636
128.    62. -3.6386031
130.    63. 0.8552304
131.    63. -0.50966059
132.    63. -0.47354559
137.    65. -1.9534796
138.    65. -0.96086419
140.    67. -0.015875729
141.    67. -0.041466669
142.    67. -1.3871099
145.    69. 2.8931587
146.    69. -1.2849569
147.    69. -2.2127883
150.    71. -0.99118163
151.    71. -1.3673929
153.    71. -1.8922444
155.    73. 2.2556468
156.    73. -1.4209409
157.    73. -0.29486705
160.    75. 0.72117233
161.    75. 1.0190017
164.    77. 0.56115283
165.    77. 3.4677529
166.    77. -0.38758378
167.    77. -0.93988979
170.    79. 1.0521958
171.    79. 2.1933898
172.    79. 0.015352506
177.    81. -0.70462686
185.    83. 1.2917595
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to get something like ...

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
    \begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
        45. 25. 0.61566929
        49. 27. 1.4956423
        53. 29. 1.0057851
        54. 29. 2.0100065
        55. 29. -3.797218
        68. 35. 1.5912051
        69. 35. 3.2076212
        72. 37. 1.4886461
        73. 37. 3.3389691
        76. 39. 3.0976278
        77. 39. 0.79048738
        81. 41. -3.4879389
        85. 43. 3.6111543
        93. 47. 2.7246307
        97. 49. -0.68090255
        104.    51. -2.0629526
        105.    51. -2.6273176
        108.    53. -0.89579787
        109.    53. 1.2111116
        112.    55. 0.91267194
        113.    55. 2.0789467
        117.    57. -0.71531635
        121.    59. -2.3426783
        127.    61. -1.8874818
        128.    61. 1.3249636
        128.    62. -3.6386031
        130.    63. 0.8552304
        131.    63. -0.50966059
        132.    63. -0.47354559
        137.    65. -1.9534796
        138.    65. -0.96086419
        140.    67. -0.015875729
        141.    67. -0.041466669
        142.    67. -1.3871099
        145.    69. 2.8931587
        146.    69. -1.2849569
        147.    69. -2.2127883
        150.    71. -0.99118163
        151.    71. -1.3673929
        153.    71. -1.8922444
        155.    73. 2.2556468
        156.    73. -1.4209409
        157.    73. -0.29486705
        160.    75. 0.72117233
        161.    75. 1.0190017
        164.    77. 0.56115283
        165.    77. 3.4677529
        166.    77. -0.38758378
        167.    77. -0.93988979
        170.    79. 1.0521958
        171.    79. 2.1933898
        172.    79. 0.015352506
        177.    81. -0.70462686
        185.    83. 1.2917595
    \end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        only marks,
        scatter,
        point meta=explicit,
    ]
        \addplot table [meta index=2] {data.txt};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Dear Stefan Pinnow. The data is right. In fact, I want to plot a three-dimensional plot in a two-dimensional figure. The first column should b considered as x-axes. The second column should be considered as y-axes. The third column should be at (the first column, the second column) with a colorful circle or square depending on its magnitude. For example, I want to have a colorful circle at ( 45, 25)  with a colorful circle depending on 0.61566929.

Comment: Please look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valley_of_stability. There three plots that are similar to what I want.

Comment: Dear Stefan Pinnow. If I want to have grid lines for each step, in both axes, what shall I do?

Comment: If you mean a grid at the axis ticks then add `grid=both` (see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247548/95441).

Comment: Great. And only if you want to: Besides accepting the answer you can also [upvote](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) it (by clicking on the arrows next to the score).