# More gridlines in plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

How can I get more gridlines, 
fx. on the x-axis for -10,-9,-8,...,14,15 and not as in my pictur -10,-5,0,5,10,15.
How do I do that?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xminorticks=true,
grid=both,
axis x line=middle,
axis y line=middle,
xmax=15, xmin=-10,
ymax=1.1, ymin=-1.1,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$\sin x$
]
\addplot[blue,mark=none,
domain=-10:10,samples=400]
{sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: My graph]

Comment: Try adding `minor x tick num=4` into the options for `\begin{axis}`. Some more details here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247541/help-with-grid-lines-in-a-pgfplot

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: Add `minor x tick num=4` into the options for `\begin{axis}`. This inserts 4 "minor ticks" between every major tick on the x-axis (the major ticks are the ones you have currently displaying).

You can use (e.g.) `minor tick num=4` if you wanted to have 4 ticks between every major tick on both the y- and x-axes.

It's also possible to have the minor and major ticks formatted differently, which can be aesthetically more pleasing. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xminorticks=true,
minor x tick num=4,
grid=both,
grid style={line width=.2pt, draw=gray!20},
major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
axis x line=middle,
axis y line=middle,
xmax=15, xmin=-10,
ymax=1.1, ymin=-1.1,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$\sin x$
]
\addplot[blue,mark=none,
domain=-10:10,samples=400]
{sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: sin x with minor ticks on x axis]